# Ionic: Optimize GPU memory

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gpu

As I am using many many CSS animations and as I know this might cause slowness in Ionic 1, I want to monitor memory performance via the *Chrome development Tools*.

When connecting my tablet (samsung galaxy tab E) to my computer and *Inspecting* it via Chrome, I see that:

- *Memory usage* (in Timeline) varies between 30Mb and 60Mb, which seems quite ok to me (correct me if I am wrong).
- *GPU memory* (in Rendering > show FPS meter) is constantly full on my tablet (40.0Mb used on 40.0Mb Max), although it is not when running the app in  desktop (7Mb on 512Mb). I read GPU memory is key in rendering animations.

**My Question**: Is there a way to increase the *Max allowed GPU memory* on my tablet? I am quite sure my tablet has more than 40Mb available, and I am administrator on all tablets running my app.

Comment: If that's not already the case, you might consider using [`Crosswalk`](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/) if you are running Android 4.3 or below. Quote from the link: "In older Android Devices (4.0-4.3), you’ll see about a 10x improvement of both HTML/CSS rendering and JavaScript performance and CSS correctness."

Comment: Thank you. With the Crosswalk cordova plugin, my max GPU memory went up to 192Mb, and the average GPU memory usage is much lower (around 10Mb). Animations or now much much smoother. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped Robijn ;-)

Comment: @Buddyshot I know this post is old, but I think you might want to post that as an answer to the question. This way, people can tell the problem was solved when navigating quickly for example.